# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

Tags: error-handling, syntax-error, k-means

Im applying K-means clustering to data frame from cvs and excel files

ref: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_iris.html#example-cluster-plot-cluster-iris-py

I try to run the code with my data from the csv file, data looks like:
[DataFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N81N7.jpg)

**However receive following errors:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('/Users/nadiastraton/Documents/workspacePython/02450Toolbox_Python/Thesis/Scripts/Clustering/cluster3.py', wdir='/Users/nadiastraton/Documents/workspacePython/02450Toolbox_Python/Thesis/Scripts/Clustering')

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

File "/Users/cluster3.py", line 46, in 
    est.fit(x.as_matrix)

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 812, in fit
    X = self._check_fit_data(X)

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py", line 786, in _check_fit_data
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64)

File "/Applications/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 373, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

print(**doc**)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

np.random.seed(5)

centers = [[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1]]

data=pd.read_csv('/DataVisualisationSample.csv')
print(data.head())


x = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Post_Share_Count','Post_Like_Count','Comment_Count'])
y = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Comment_Like_Count'])

print(x.info())


estimators = {'k_means_data_3': KMeans(n_clusters=3),
              'k_means_data_8': KMeans(n_clusters=12),
              'k_means_data_bad_init': KMeans(n_clusters=3, n_init=1,
                                              init='random')}


fignum = 1
for name, est in estimators.items():
    fig = plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
    plt.clf()
    ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)

    plt.cla()
    est.fit(x.as_matrix)
    labels = est.labels_

    ax.scatter(x[:, 2], x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=labels.astype(np.int))

    ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.set_xlabel('Post_Share_Count')
    ax.set_ylabel('Post_Like_Count')
    ax.set_zlabel('Comment_Count')
    fignum = fignum + 1

# Plot the ground truth
fig = plt.figure(fignum, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.clf()
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, .95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)

plt.cla()

for name, label in [('Popular', 0),
                    ('Not Popular', 1),
                    ('Least Popular', 2)]:
    ax.text3D(x[y == label, 2].mean(),
              x[y == label, 0].mean() + 1.5,
              x[y == label, 1].mean(), name,
              horizontalalignment='center',
              bbox=dict(alpha=.5, edgecolor='w', facecolor='w'))
# Reorder the labels to have colors matching the cluster results
y = np.choose(y, [1, 2, 0]).astype(np.int)
ax.scatter(x[:, 2], x[:, 0], x[:, 1], c=y).astype(np.int)

ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_xlabel('Post_Share_Count')
ax.set_ylabel('Post_Like_Count')
ax.set_zlabel('Comment_Count')
plt.show()
```

Tried to fix errors:

(est.fit(x.as_matrix) instead of est.fit(x))
   **and**
(c=labels.astype(np.int) instead of c=labels.astype(np.float)) - (all values in my file are int.)

However changing from np.float to np.int does not fix it.